# How to responsive the table content generated by plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, calendar

I am working with event plus plugin of WordPress that is used for showing the calendar with event information that is calendar generated by the short code of the plugin.

But when I see calendar on  **360*640 or 320*480** resolution calendar is not showing properly. How to responsive this calendar it is using the table.

Here is my site [link](https://manresa-sj.com/general-calendar/)

Please give some idea how to resolve it.

Comment: you can show by week event o  mobile view?

Comment: I just want to show full calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.responsive-table {
  overflow-x: auto;
  min-height: 0.01%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .responsive-table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .responsive-table > .calendar-table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .responsive-table > .calendar-table > thead > tr > th,
  .responsive-table > .calendar-table > thead > tr > td,
  .responsive-table > .calendar-table > tbody > tr > th,
  .responsive-table > .calendar-table > tbody > tr > td, {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

You need to add your table inside a div with class .responsive-table. This will create a horizontal scrollbar and will be easy to use on smaller devices.